# Restaurar respaldo de tabla en sql y php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'XXXXXXX';
   $dbuser = 'XXXXXXX';
   $dbpass = 'XXXXXXX';

   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $table_name = "chofer";
   $backup_file  = "chofer.sql";
   $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$backup_file' INTO TABLE $table_name";

   mysqli_select_db($conn,'test_db');
   $retval = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('No se puede acceder al registro : ' . mysql_error());
   }

  echo "<script>";
  echo "alert ('Restauración exitosa.');";
  echo "window.location.replace('index.php');";
  echo "</script>";

   mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Con este script se debe restaurar la tabla chofer con la información del archivo chofer.sql, pero marca este error "No se puede acceder al registro" y no restaura la tabla, ahora bien la idea es que pregunte de que archivo desea restaurar y de igual forma restaure todas las tablas contenidas en el archivo .sql, espero me puedan ayudar con este dilema, muchas gracias.

Este es el archivo con el que respaldo las tablas

```
<?php

backup_tables('XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX');

function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

   $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
   mysqli_select_db($link,$name);

   //get all of the tables
   if($tables == '*')
   {
      $tables = array();
      $result = mysqli_query($link,'SHOW TABLES');
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
      {
         $tables[] = $row[0];
      }
   }
   else
   {
      $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
   }

   //cycle through
   foreach($tables as $table)
   {
      $result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM '.$table);
      $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);

      $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
      $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link,'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
      $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
      {
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
         {
            $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
            for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
            {
               $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
               $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
               if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
               if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
            }
            $return.= ");\n";
         }
      }
      $return.="\n\n\n";
   }

   //save file
   $handle = fopen('db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
   fwrite($handle,$return);
   fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. Si el arhchivo es un script SQL (como sugiere su extensión), no hace falta hacer un `LOAD DATA`, sino ejecutar el script. 2. Si no es un script SQL, te sugiero utilizar otra extensión. 3. Abrir la posibilidad a que alguien ejecute un script SQL en tu servidor implica que esa persona puede hacer lo que quiera, incluso, destruir los datos o las estructuras.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario pero tengo un script que genera un archivo .sql para respaldar así las tablas y su información pero lo que me falta es que se pueda restaurar cualquiera de los archivos generados por este script, por ello he intentado utilizar el código que he subido a este sitio, tomando encuenta esto, que cambios sugieres que realice en el código arriba mencionado?

Comment: Demos una mirada a unas cuantas líneas del archivo .SQL que te genera el respaldo de las tablas.

Comment: DROP TABLE XXXXX;

CREATE TABLE `XXXXX` (
  `XXX` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `XXX` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `XXXX` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `XXXX` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `XXXX` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `XXXX` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `XXXX` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `XXXX` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `XXXX` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

Esto es mas meno lo que se graba en el archivo sql.

Comment: He agregado el script del archivo con el que respaldo las tablas al mensaje original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu lo que buscas es ejecutar un script SQL desde php.

Antes del código de la *solución*, es mi deber recomendarte **no permitir** a un usuario cualquiera ejecutar SQL arbitrario en tu servidor, pues con eso abres la puerta a que un usuario medianamente capaz pueda destruir los datos y sus estructuras.

Dicho esto, y luego de haber visto la rutina que genera el *backup*, lo que tienes es un script SQL que contiene varias sentencias (una para borrar la tabla, otra para crearla de nuevo, y múltiples `insert` de las filas de datos).

Utiliza la función [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) para ejecutar todo el contenido del script `SQL` en una sola llamada. Siguiendo las líneas de tu ejemplo, sería algo como:

```
<?php
  $dbhost = 'XXXXXXX';
  $dbuser = 'XXXXXXX';
  $dbpass = 'XXXXXXX';

  $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

  if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $backup_file  = "/path/to/chofer.sql";
  $sql = file_get_contents($backup_file);

  mysqli_select_db($conn,'test_db');

  if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
    do {
      /* almacenar primer juego de resultados */
      if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
          printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
      }
      /* mostrar divisor */
      if (mysqli_more_results($link)) {
        printf("-----------------\n");
      }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
  }


echo "<script>";
echo "alert ('Restauración exitosa.');";
echo "window.location.replace('index.php');";
echo "</script>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Es probable que el código tenga algún error de sintaxis, la idea es que te orientes con él y produzcas tu propia solución.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias lo voy a checar.